# Accordion Z-Index bug

Tags: jquery, css, z-index

I'm using a accordion for some filters and have some text beneath it. I want the accordion to over lay the text as a layer. In the code below, the accordion pushes the text down.

I tried using z-index but it doesn't seem to be working. Any help / ideas on what's wrong?

Thanks a ton!
Vila

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        font-family: 'Arial', sans-serif;
    }


    .accordion-container {
        width: 20%;
        float:left;
        margin-right: 3px;

    }
    .accordion-toggle {
        display: block;
        padding: 13px 10px 10px 10px;
        font-size: 1em;
        font-weight: 400;
        background: #535860;
        color: #fff;
        text-decoration: none;
        vertical-align: middle;
        letter-spacing: 0.1em;
    }
    .accordion-toggle.open {
        background: #E84A2B;
        color: #fff;
    }
    .accordion-toggle:hover {
        background: #E84A2B;
    }
    .accordion-toggle span.toggle-icon {
        position: absolute;
        top: 9px;
        right: 12px;
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: 400;
    }
    .accordion-content {
        margin-top: 3px;
        display: none;
        overflow: auto;
        background-color: #535860;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        -moz-box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
        box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .accordion-content img {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        margin: 0 15px 10px 0;
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }


    /* media query for mobile */
    @media (max-width: 960px) {
        .accordion-container {
        width: 100%;
        float:left;
        position:relative;
    }
        .content {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }
        .accordion-content {
            padding: 10px 0;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    }
</style>

</head>

<body>

    <div class = "main" style = "position:relative; z-index: 999;">

    <div class="accordion-container">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">ROME<span class="toggle-icon">
            <!--<i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>-->+        

            </span></a>
        <div class="accordion-content l1">
            <img src="images/italy-thumb_rome.jpg" />
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-container">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">ROME<span class="toggle-icon">+</span></a>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <img src="images/italy-thumb_rome.jpg" />
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-container">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">ROME<span class="toggle-icon">+</span></a>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <img src="images/italy-thumb_rome.jpg" />
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="accordion-container">
        <a href="#" class="accordion-toggle">ROME<span class="toggle-icon">+</span></a>
        <div class="accordion-content">
            <img src="images/italy-thumb_rome.jpg" />
            <p>Test</p>
        </div>
    </div>          

        <p style = "position:relative; z-index: -999;">Random Text Area unit</p>
    </div>

    <!-------------------- JS -------------------->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.accordion-toggle').on('click', function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
            // create accordion variables
            var accordion = $(this);
            var accordionContent = accordion.next('.accordion-content');
            var accordionToggleIcon = $(this).children('.toggle-icon');

            // toggle accordion link open class
            accordion.toggleClass("open");
            // toggle accordion content
            accordionContent.slideToggle(90);

            // change plus/minus icon
            if (accordion.hasClass("open")) {
                accordionToggleIcon.html("–");
            } else {
                accordionToggleIcon.html("+");
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: remove `/* margin-top: 3px; */` from `.accordion-content` and try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elements having position `relative` are still in normal flow, hence it will be pushed down when new content is added above. If you want to overlay something, you should take either of the elements out of normal flow using something like `position:absolute` or `position:fixed`

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7z6Lj58y/)